# How to unmount webcomponent used inside react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using web component inside react component. when I unmount react component, it seems web component inside react component is not being unmounted properly, because when I mount the react component again, webcomponent props update method is being called and then throws error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

I am using skate js to create webcomponent.

How to properly unmount the web component. please help, I would always be thakful.

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I find your question too vague - you need to provide your implementation of webcomponent created by skatejs, as well as the React component containing it. If the code is too long or unable to be shared here, please try to create a simple example using Codesandbox or any tool to replicate your issue.

Comment: yes code is too long that's the reason i didnt provide. i will create the sandbox and share it. thank you. @blaz

Comment: I just thought if anyone have gone through this issue then then can provide their inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The Widget component was not being unmounted properly. I have to remove it forcefully form dom using

[Mozilla docs removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

After that it works fine.